# Superimposing points on a pdf chart

Tags: python, django, pdf, graph, charts

I am trying to create an online app where specific data points need to superimposed or put on a specific chart (from WHO).
https://www.dietitians.ca/Downloads/Public/LFA-WFA_Birth-24_BOYS_SET-2_EN.aspx

What is the simplest way to accomplish this so points can be place on-top of this exact graph? The app will be built with Python/Django.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The simplest way would be to create a new one page PDF and draw the data points in the positions you need them to be then overlay the new PDF on top of PDF you got from the service. You can do that with most PDF library tools.

Comment: Which PDF library tools are you referring to? Is there some sort of documentation on this?

Comment: The tool you use is up to you. There are a number of PDF libraries that you could use to generate the new page and overlay it on the chart. You'll need to research that one yourself. The documentation will be specific to the tool.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [PyMuPDF](http://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to draw a circle for a point in the location(s) desired. Here's some example code:

```python
import fitz  # pip install PyMuPDF

src_pdf_filename = 'LFA-WFA_Birth-24_BOYS_SET-2_EN.pdf'
dst_pdf_filename = 'LFA-WFA_Birth-24_BOYS_SET-2_EN_Edited.pdf'

document = fitz.open(src_pdf_filename)

# Get the first page
page = document[0]

# Draw a circle for a point in the upper right part of page
# http://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/page/#Page.drawCircle
page.drawCircle(fitz.Point(517, 147), 5, color=(1, 0, 0), fill=(1, 0, 0))

# Keep original PDF; save to different PDF
document.save(dst_pdf_filename, garbage=4, clean=True, deflate=True)
document.close()
```